# rendering a component inside a react page using Menu

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a menu and the main body of the page. I have created different pages as components with some text. All I want is that when I click on the side bar menu, the components are displayed in the main page. How can I make this work?

```
const items2 =  [{
  label: 'Rice',
  key: 'rice',
},
{
  label: 'AB Test',
  key: 'ab', 
}]

const MainLayout = () => {
  const {
    token: { colorBgContainer },
  } = theme.useToken();

const navigate = useNavigate();
const onClick = (e)=>{navigate(`/${e.key}`)}

  return (
    <Layout>
         <Sider >
            <Menu
              mode="inline"
              items={items2}
              onClick = {onClick}

            />
          </Sider>
          <Content >
```

//I Want to open the pages here

```
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render a component inside other component, React provides a special props name `children`.

To achieve your requirement, you can do like this:

**MainLayout.js**:

```
export const MainLayout = ({children}) => {
  const {
    token: { colorBgContainer },
  } = theme.useToken();

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const onClick = (e)=>{navigate(`/${e.key}`)}

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Sider>
        <Menu
          mode="inline"
          items={items2}
          onClick={onClick}
        />
      </Sider>
      <Content>
        {children}
      </Content>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

In `MainLayout.js`, you only need to write `{children}` inside component `<Content>`, *React will do the rest for you* to pass the content of Rice or AB or whatever for you. In each page, just place `<MainLayout>` at the top of the outer of rest of your code.

Please see 2 example files below.

---

**Rice.js**:

```
import MainLayout from './MainLayout';

export const Rice = () => {
  // Do some stuffs here...

  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <div>
        <h2>Best rated rice in the World</h2>
        <ol>
          <li>Pinipig</li>
          <li>Riz de Camargue</li>
          ...
        </ol>
      <div>
    </MainLayout>
  )
}
```

---

**Corn.js**:

```
import MainLayout from './MainLayout';

export const Corn = () => {
  // Do some stuffs here...

  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <div>
        <h2>Best Corn Side Dish Recipes</h2>
        <ol>
          <li>Whipped-Cream Corn Salad</li>
          <li>Classic Grilled Corn on the Cob</li>
          ...
        </ol>
      <div>
    </MainLayout>
  )
}
```

You can read more and play around with the example code from [React's official documents](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

It is the basic concept of React, so before you start to build something big, I suggest to follow this docs first or find some series of React tutorials for beginner, they will explain key concepts of React so you would not save more time.

Comment: I am still not clear on how to use the children. MainLayout.js: is where I want to show the different <Rice/ > or <AB /> components based on clicking on the menu.

Comment: Anything is wrapped by the component <MainLayout> is consider as the children. Take an example, you have file Rice.js, in that file, you write code of page "Rice" inside the component <MainLayout>, so all of that is passed in the props `children`.

I will edit my answer for you to clearer about this.

Comment: I edited the answer. As you've already had the react-router-dom, you can copy the code above and play around to see the results.

Comment: Awesome. You are best! Works now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use react-router-dom to navigate when you click other MenuItem. Create your own [RouterProvider](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router-provider) and put it in the Content.

```
<Content>
 <RouterProvider router={router}>
</Content>
```

**EDIT**

Now you have two way to navigate to your Component. First is using Link and set it to your label.

```
{
  label: <Link title="Rice" to="/rice">Rice</Link>,
  key: 'rice', 
}
```

Second way is hook useNavigate

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const onClick = (e)=>{navigate(`/${e.key}`)}
//Add to Menu
<Menu
  onClick={onClick}
//other props
/>
```

Comment: Can you give me some more specifics. I am beginner to React.  I looked at the Router Provider...  Where do I insert this code mentioned in the RouterProvider link? and then how do I access it via the menu ?

Comment: So I get that I need to add this code in the content section. When I call path/rice then it will render the component <Rice/>  but now how do I call the link in my Menu... ive updated my main comment to show what I have done next   <Router>
      <div>
         
        <hr />
 
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/rice">
            <Rice />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/abtest">
            <ABTest />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can follow it to continue

Comment: so I am able to call navigate to the pages when I click on the menu.. but my requirement is to open those pages between the <Content>   </Content> so it renders while I keep the menu side bar/layout in place